# Dynamic form from JSON input swift

Tags: swift

i have a json file from which i am trying to create a dynamic for in swift with 3 pages I have passed the json data into a model using Codable and I can print it. This JSON has 3 pages which I suppose would be 3 UIViewController. How do I create this dynamic form because I seem confused. This is what I have tried so far

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let data = stubbedResponse("forms") else {return}
        do {
            let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(BaseModel.self, from: data)
            print(decoded)
        } catch {

        }
    }

    func stubbedResponse(_ filename: String) -> Data! {
        @objc class VC: NSObject {}

        let bundle = Bundle(for: VC.self)
        let path = bundle.path(forResource: filename, ofType: "json")
        return (try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)))
    }
}
```

JSON:

```
{
  "id": "form_1",
  "name": "Pet Adoption Application Form",
  "pages": [
    {
      "label": "Page 1",
      "sections": [
        {
          "label": "Welcome to Pets Rescue",
          "elements": [
            {
              "type": "embeddedphoto",
              "file": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/8700/wall-animal-dog-pet.jpg?cs=srgb&dl=animal-collar-dog-8700.jpg&fm=jpg",
              "unique_id": "embeddedphoto_1",
              "rules": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "Basic Info",
          "elements": [
            {
              "type": "text",
              "label": "Your fullname",
              "isMandatory": true,
              "unique_id": "text_1",
              "rules": []
            },
            {
              "type": "text",
              "label": "Email address",
              "isMandatory": true,
              "unique_id": "text_2",
              "rules": []
            },
            {
              "type": "formattednumeric",
              "label": "Phone Number",
              "keyboard": "numeric",
              "formattedNumeric": "####-###-####",
              "isMandatory": true,
              "unique_id": "formattednumeric_1",
              "rules": []
            },
            {
              "type": "datetime",
              "mode": "date",
              "label": "Date of Birth",
              "isMandatory": true,
              "unique_id": "datetime_1",
              "rules": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "Page 2",
      "sections": [
        {
          "label": "About your home",
          "elements": [
            {
              "type": "yesno",
              "label": "Do you have a yard?",
              "isMandatory": true,
              "unique_id": "yesno_1",
              "rules": [
                {
                  "condition": "equals",
                  "value": "Yes",
                  "action": "show",
                  "otherwise": "hide",
                  "targets": [
                    "text_3"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "text",
              "label": "Is it fenced? Also indicate the type",
              "isMandatory": false,
              "unique_id": "text_3",
              "rules": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "Page 3",
      "sections": [
        {
          "label": "Additional Information",
          "elements": [
            {
              "type": "text",
              "label": "Please provide your veterinarian's name",
              "isMandatory": false,
              "unique_id": "text_4",
              "rules": []
            },
            {
              "type": "text",
              "label": "Please provide the name of a personal reference",
              "isMandatory": true,
              "unique_id": "text_5",
              "rules": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I understand a tableView could also be used in this instance with a button that signifies next page

Comment: can you attach the json

Comment: okay I would do that

Comment: added JSON @Sh_Khan

Comment: Have you considered a scrolled table?

Comment: No, @Ron how can I do it? tableview

Comment: each element inside the `pages` array is a sign of a tableView's datasource , it's up to you to show them in 1 vc with sections or show 1 section per vc

Comment: yes. Exactly @Sh_Khan

Answer (score 0):

You have this structure

```
struct BaseModel {  
 let pages: [Model] 
}
```

You will have a vc that you should display recursively like

```
class SomeVC:UIViewController {
  var currentIndex = 0
  var pages = [Model]()
}
```

if you have say a tableView structured there then inside a next page action

```
let next = currentIndex + 1
if next < pages.count {
  let vc = SomeVC()
  vc.currentIndex = next
  vc.pages = pages
 // push the vc
}
else {
 // no more
}
```

Also you have an option to make this array inside a singleton

Comment: is it not possible to use one VC and use tableview?

Comment: how would I condition the UI

Comment: Do I just create UI programmatically and choose which UI gets displayed or how.Please kindly expantiante

Comment: If the UI for all pages is the same , then yes the tableview is best for it , it make no difference to make the ui in IB / programmatically as finally it'll be a matter of loading the vc ,

Comment: This also prints nothing `pages.forEach { (page) in
            print("PAGE \(page.label)")
        }` after parsing my JSON

Comment: `print(pages.count)` and see whether it's empty

Comment: it prints 0 in the console

Comment: `print(String(data:data,encoding:.utf8))` and see you string json may be it's empty there

Comment: Figured I was not appending to the pages

Comment: I figured I can't create VC. pages could be increased in the file.json and when that occures, the application would crash